# component doesnt trigger rowEditingStopped event listener when added in cell Renderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

version that breaks, v28.1.0 when frameworkcomponents is deprecated for component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-complex-editor-swzgat?file=index.html,package.json,src%2Fcolumns.js,src%2FApp.js

the first link shows a code snipplet of the working component where an eventlistener is added in the cellrenderer. onRowEditingStopped is triggered.

however after uprev to v28.1.0 it doesnt work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-complex-editor-6blxsz?file=index.html,src%2FApp.js,src%2Fcolumns.js,package.json,src%2FComponents%2FRenderers%2FActionsRenderer.jsx